# ROW_NUMBER is not working in CTE

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, with-statement, row-number

I was playing around reports and it appeared that row_number is not working in recursion.

!! I have simplified the example!!

From table with 3 records:

```
declare @sometable table (id int, id2 int)
insert into @sometable
select 1 as id,   11 as id2   
union all
select 2,         22   
union all
select 3,        33
```

In CTE select All and mark first record to be excluded on the next iteration:

```
;with cte(iteration, ord, id, id2, deal) as 
(
select ordered.*
    , deal = (case when ord = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
from 
    (select 1 iteration,
        ord = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id),
        st.*
    FROM @sometable st) ordered

)
select * from CTE
union all
    select 
    ordersinverted.nextIteration,
    ordersinverted.ord,
    ordersinverted.id,              
    ordersinverted.id2,
    deal = (case when ord = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
from (
    select 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ord ORDER BY iteration desc) as reversedIteration,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cte.id) as ord,
        iteration + 1 as nextIteration,                 
        cte.id, 
        cte.id2                 
    from cte 
    where cte.deal = 0
) ordersinverted
```

It gives me an expected result for 3 iterations:
Use row_number [out of CTE result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5elKd.png)

I would very much like to get similar result and recursively called select. Unfortunately this is where bug is suspected to have place:

```
;with cte(iteration, ord, id, id2, deal) as 
(
    select ordered.*
        , deal = (case when ord = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
    from 
        (select 1 iteration,
            ord = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id),
            st.*
        FROM @sometable st) ordered
union all
    select 
        ordersinverted.nextIteration,
        ordersinverted.ord,
        ordersinverted.id,              
        ordersinverted.id2,
        deal = (case when ord = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
    from (
        select 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ord ORDER BY iteration desc) as     reversedIteration,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cte.id) as ord,
            iteration + 1 as nextIteration,                 
            cte.id, 
            cte.id2                 
        from cte 
        where cte.deal = 0
    ) ordersinverted
)
select * from CTE
```

Use row_number [within CTE result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpqhb.png)

Oh, Sorry. This must have a question format:
So my Question is: Is this a feature or a bug?

Please note that similar query for Oracle would work as expected:

```
with T (id,grp_id) as (
select 1 as id,1 as grp_id from dual union all
select 2 as id,1 as grp_id from dual union all
select 3 as id,1 as grp_id from dual union all
select 1 as id,2 as grp_id from dual union all
select 2 as id,2 as grp_id from dual union all
select 3 as id,2 as grp_id from dual )
,
rec (id,grp_id,rn) as (
 select id, grp_id, row_number()over(partition by grp_id order by id) rn from T where grp_id=1 
 union all
 select t.id, t.grp_id, row_number() over(partition by t.grp_id  order by t.id) rn from T inner join rec on t.id=rec.id and t.grp_id=rec.grp_id+1

)
```

PS. It works similarly if to use max() or min() functions...

Comment: I don't really have an idea about what you're trying to achieve/select but I suspect, your problem lies in the mixing of sub-queries, row_number and the recursive cte and the order sql server executes the query in. I think you're overcomplicating the query needlessly by doing that. But as I don't really know what you're actually trying to do, based on the input, I cannot specify better.
Instead of trying to do everything in a single query - split it up into smaller steps.

Comment: what I would try is 1) create the CTE without the row_number in it 2) create CTE2 which is a Select of CTE with the row_number in it.  I'm not sure if you could try that

Comment: Thanks for recommendations on how to workaround. This however is more up to describe the problem that exists in MS SQL. 
This script does work in Oracle. Will Add sample one here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a documented behavior. Hence it should be considered as a "feature". Here is the documentation for this case: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

> Analytic and aggregate functions in the recursive part of the CTE are
>   applied to the set for the current recursion level and not to the set
>   for the CTE. Functions like ROW_NUMBER operate only on the subset of
>   data passed to them by the current recursion level and not the entire
>   set of data passed to the recursive part of the CTE. For more
>   information, see example K. Using analytical functions in a recursive
>   CTE that follows.

Paragraph K of this article has a nice demo for the behavior of ROW_NUMBER function in a recursive CTE. Because recursive CTE process data row-by-row, ROW_NUMBER in the recursive part of the CTE will always return 1. You can change `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id)` to `COUNT(*) OVER ()` to check how many rows SQL Server process at once for the anchor and for the recursive part of the CTE. There will be 3 and 1 respectively.