# Unexpected data at typical recursion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, window-functions, recursive-query

It's hard for me to use words to describe this, so here's the sample:

```
select *
into t
from (values (10, 'A'),
             (25, 'B'),
             (30, 'C'),
             (45, 'D'),
             (52, 'E'),
             (61, 'F'),
             (61, 'G'),
             (61, 'H'),
             (79, 'I'),
             (82, 'J')
) v(userid, name)
```

Notice how F,G and H have the same userid.

Now, consider the following recursive query:

```
with tn as 
(
    select t.userId,t.name, row_number() over (order by userid,newid()) as seqnum
    from t
),
cte as 
(
        select userId, name,  seqnum as seqnum
        from tn 
        where seqnum = 1
    union all
        select tn.userId, tn.name,tn.seqnum
        from 
            cte 
            inner join tn on tn.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
)
select *
from cte
```

The first cte,`tn`, creates a row_number which includes a randomization component that will cause F/G/H to appear in random order. However, they will all still appear once each(easily checkable by modifying the last and outermost `from` to be `from tn`)

The second cte, `cte`, recursively scans `tn`. There's nothing too complicated in it because it comes from a minimized example. However, it is evident that the anchor member is manually set to be `tn`'s first line, and then the recursion scans all the rest lines.

However, the final result-set does not have F/G/H appear once each! They all appear in 3 lines total, but in any combination. FGH is possible, but so is FFH, and even FFF! Here's an FHH example:

```
+--------+------+--------+
| userId | name | seqnum |
+--------+------+--------+
|     10 | A    |      1 |
|     25 | B    |      2 |
|     30 | C    |      3 |
|     45 | D    |      4 |
|     52 | E    |      5 |
|     61 | F    |      6 |
|     61 | H    |      7 |
|     61 | H    |      8 |
|     79 | I    |      9 |
|     82 | J    |     10 |
+--------+------+--------+
```

**Why is that?**

I don't think [analytic function behaviour within ctes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445320/row-number-is-not-working-in-cte) has anything to do with it, because `tn` which includes the row_number is not recursive.

For the record, I got this question due to the following sequence of events:
Someone asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62129188/t-sql-loop-through-all-rows-and-sum-amount-from-column-until-value-is-reached) that was answered by an [excellent contributor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff).
The same OP asked [a follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62292675/randomize-part-of-select-from-cte-output/62297213?noredirect=1#comment110195122_62297213), which I though I could answer with a bit of tampering on the original. However, after digging a bit, I found a behaviour I cannot understand. I made the example minimal as much as i could.

Comment: Please show us your current results, and the results that you would like to get.

Comment: There is randomization, so the results are not always the same. And it's not what I "want", but what I expected. Anyway, I guess i'll put one result set on.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. Running your query repeatidly in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=93770bd90decee3ed6672bf9e1f9e1fb), I did reproduce the issue. I think that David Browne has the correct solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CTE's aren't spooled.  Every reference to `tn` may result in re-running the query and re-randomizing the results.

To avoid this, run the randomizing query once and load a temp table.  eg

```
select t.userId,t.name, row_number() over (order by userid,newid()) as seqnum
into #tn
from t
```

and reference that in your subsequent query

```
with tn as 
(
    select * from #tn
),
cte as 
(
        select userId, name,  seqnum as seqnum
        from tn
        where seqnum = 1
    union all
        select tn.userId, tn.name,tn.seqnum
        from 
            cte 
            inner join tn on tn.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
)
select *
from cte
```